# Phing can't see PHPUnit

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, phing

I'm trying to setup a new Continuous Integration server that utilizes Phing and PHPUnit for automatically running test cases.

I've installed Phing with Pear:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
pear install phing/phing
```

I've installed PHPUnit using the new PHAR method:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Then I go to the directory where my build.xml file is located, rung phing and it looks like Phing has no idea where PHPUnit is.

```
[jenkins@leroy workspace]$ phing
Buildfile: /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Framework/workspace/build.xml

Framework > test:

 [echo] Running Tests
Execution of target "test" failed for the following reason: /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Framework/workspace/build.xml:9:37: /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Framework/workspace/build.xml:9:37: PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed

BUILD FAILED
/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Framework/workspace/build.xml:9:37:
/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Framework/workspace/build.xml:9:37: PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed
Total time: 0.0764 seconds

[jenkins@leroy workspace]$
```

Checked the location of Phing and PHPUnit:

```
[jenkins@leroy workspace]$ which phing
/usr/bin/phing
[jenkins@leroy workspace]$ which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

And, making sure PHP is new enough:

```
[jenkins@leroy workspace]$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)
```

I'm doing all of this because we're replacing an older Jenkins server with this new one.  Trying to use the newest software, but I can't figure out how to tell Phing where to find PHPUnit.

Thanks in advance for any help!

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are some actual issues with phing and the latest 4.x versions of PHPUnit: http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1091.

So to fix the issue, I removed PHPUnit 4 and specified an older version:

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.7.35
```

Phing and PHPUnit worked immediately at this point.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you install PHPUnit via PEAR if they suspended this channel about a year ago: http://pear.phpunit.de/ Please share what you know :)

Comment: Could you please help me. There is an open bounty to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405597/unable-to-globally-install-older-version-of-phpunit-phar

Comment: As pointed out by yegor256, the pear installation will not work. Phar installation can be done. You can find all released of PHPUnit that are available as PHAR on phar.phpunit.de. PHPUnit 3.7.35, for instance, is at phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-3.7.35.phar.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like adding the `pharlocation` attribute to the `phpunit` task element, pointing to your local phpunit executable, does the job:

```
<phpunit haltonfailure="true" haltonerror="true" 
    bootstrap="./fw_init.php" 
    pharlocation="/usr/local/bin/phpunit">
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        ...
</phpunit>
```

Comment: my test fails when trying to `require 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php'`, since this file is not on the include path. how did you solve that?

Comment: I tried this but still not working. There is an open bounty to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405597/unable-to-globally-install-older-version-of-phpunit-phar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guy with exactly the same problem: [How do I tell Phing where PHPUnit is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799044/how-do-i-tell-phing-where-phpunit-is-installed?rq=1)

His theory is that:

> PHP version on this machine could be too old and not be able to handle PHAR archives

I can't comment if he is right or not, but that question received no replies from anyone other than the author

Comment: Yes, I read that question and that's why I included my PHP version in my original question.  PHAR requires a minimum version of 5.3.3, so I don't believe that's my problem.

Comment: Could you please help me. There is an open bounty to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405597/unable-to-globally-install-older-version-of-phpunit-phar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly remark, but do you have `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` in your PHP include path?

I get the same error when I remove the location of `phpunit.phar` from my include path.

Comment: Could you please help me. There is an open bounty to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405597/unable-to-globally-install-older-version-of-phpunit-phar