# Unable to globally install older version of phpunit phar

Tags: php, phpunit, phing

As given in https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.phar.verification, the steps to globally install the PHAR are:

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
$ chmod +x phpunit.phar
$ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit x.y.z by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

I followed the above, but with the URL for the older version, i.e. https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-old.phar (because our PHP version is older). I ran the following commands then -

```
$ chmod +x phpunit-old.phar
$ sudo mv phpunit-old.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

*Note - My PHP version is 5.3.29. and the Old Stable Release section in phpunit.de says PHPUnit 4.8 is supported on PHP 5.3, PHP 5.4, PHP 5.5, and PHP 5.6.*

Looks fine till here. But, running `phpunit --version` gives -

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Cannot redeclare class phpunit_extensions_database_constraint_tableisequal in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 109
zend_mm_heap corrupted
```

So, instead of moving the `.phar` to `/usr/local/bin/` (in the step 3), I was managing so far by running this -

```
$ php phpunit-old.phar –-version
```

I was also able to run my unit test cases in this way -

```
php /home/sandeepan/phpunit-old.phar /var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/openx/lib/ad_agencies/unittests/Admarvel_generic_network_test.php
```

But, now I need to integrate phpunit with phing. I would like to use the basic utilities provided by [PHPUnitTask of phing](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/PHPUnitTask.html). So, I guess it needs phpunit phar to be globally installed.

I tried my luck by writing the following -

```
<phpunit haltonfailure="true" haltonerror="true" 
                                            pharlocation="/home/sandeepan/phpunit-old">
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
    <batchtest>
        <fileset dir="${dir.scratchpad}/${dir.subdir}/unittests">
            <include name="**/*_test.php"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</phpunit>
```

But I get this error -

```
BUILD FAILED
...
: PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed
```

**Update**

With reference to stackoverflow.com/a/23410676/351903, I tried with this older version of Phpunit, i.e. PHPUnit-3.7.35. Now, `phpunit --version` command works. But I still have no success using the PHPUnitTask of Phing. Still getting `PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed` error.

**Update 2**

The solution which worked for me was using PHPUnit 3.7.35. It seems there is some compatibility issue of phing with PHPUnit 4.8.

Comment: Using PHPUnit 3.7.35 fixed the problem. Source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377750/phing-cant-see-phpunit/23410676#23410676

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me was using PHPUnit 3.7.35. It seems there is some compatibility issue of phing with PHPUnit 4.8.

Source - [Phing can't see PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377750/phing-cant-see-phpunit/23410676#23410676)

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded the old PHPUnit file you provided from the phpunit.de website, and have applied succesfully the commands you wrote. Running phpunit worked like a charm in my case.

Perhaps there is an incompatibility between your PHP version and the PHPUnit version you downloaded?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.3.29. and the Old Stable Release section in https://phpunit.de/ says PHPUnit 4.8 is supported on PHP 5.3, PHP 5.4, PHP 5.5, and PHP 5.6.

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with the loading/require statements. Could you show us your phpunit.xml file if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue you describe:

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-old.phar
--2016-04-07 09:47:35--  https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-old.phar
Resolving phar.phpunit.de (phar.phpunit.de)... 188.94.27.25
Connecting to phar.phpunit.de (phar.phpunit.de)|188.94.27.25|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-4.8.24.phar [following]
--2016-04-07 09:47:35--  https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-4.8.24.phar
Reusing existing connection to phar.phpunit.de:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3086772 (2.9M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘phpunit-old.phar’

phpunit-old.phar                                          100%[=====================================================================================================================================>]   2.94M  3.97MB/s    in 0.7s    

2016-04-07 09:47:36 (3.97 MB/s) - ‘phpunit-old.phar’ saved [3086772/3086772]


$ php phpunit-old.phar --version
PHPUnit 4.8.24 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Comment: I am also able to run `php phpunit-old.phar --version` but unable to run `phpunit --version`.

Comment: With reference to http://stackoverflow.com/a/23410676/351903, I would like to try with this older version of Phpunit, i.e. PHPUnit-3.7.35. What is the download URL for its phar package?

Comment: You can find all released of PHPUnit that are available as PHAR on https://phar.phpunit.de/. PHPUnit 3.7.35, for instance, is at https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-3.7.35.phar.

Comment: Thanks. And FYI, `phpunit --version` command worked with this older version. But I still have no success using the PHPUnitTask of Phing. Still getting `PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed` error.

Comment: Correction - using PHPUnit 3.7.35 fixed the problem. I had an incorrect observation last time - "Still getting PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed error".

Comment: Awarded bounty, because you helped me in getting the PHAR :)